# IE 11 does not display content in an iframe with a dynamically assigned URL using vb.net. It show error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

We are trying to build https url using vb.net code and assign the iframe source using vb.net version 4.0 . It is showing this error.

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame To help protect the
>   security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of
>   this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame. What you
>   can try: Open this content in a new window.

Comment: This is your own page?

Comment: Does this occur when you hard code the url? If it still occurs, than it's the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header. If you control the other site, you can look into whether that is being set and how.